# Retried stages mark build as failed

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have some stages with retries, something like:

```
stage('Deploy') {
    options {
        retry(2)
    }
    steps {
        script {
            <... snip ...>
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that, when these stages fail in a try, even if it is successful in the second try, they will be marked as failure.

Note that all stages are marked as success, only the build is marked as failure. In the image the retried stage is highlighted:
[image: Stages]

Is that normal? how to ignore failed tries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone comes across the same issue, I use my own try/catch function that will print the error in red:

```
def retry(retries, block) {
    while(retries > 0) {
        retries--
        try {           
            block(retries)
            return
        } catch(Exception exception) {
            printf "######################################\n" + 
                   "\u001B[31mFAILED!!! Retries left = " + retries + "\n" +
                   "ERROR:\n" + exception.toString() + "\n" +
                   "STACK TRACE:\n" + exception.getStackTrace() + "\u001B[0m\n" +        
                   "######################################"
            if(retries == 0) {
                throw exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
retry(3) { retriesLeft ->
    printf "retries left: ${retriesLeft}"
}
```